# Check if a certain value in one table references to all possible rows on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `"buys"` that contains `clientID` and `itemName` and other irrelvent columns, and another table `"item"` that contains `"itemName"` and `itemType` columns.
I need a query that will show me **all  clients that bought all possible items** in `"item"` table, without using count functions.
I tried using `"exist"` and `"not exists"` but couldn't find a way to use it.

> SELECT * from buys ;

```
 cid | rno | iname        | amount 
-----+-----+--------------+-------- 
   2 |   1 | orange juice | 2 
   1 |   2 | orange juice | 1 
   2 |   1 | macchiato    | 2
   1 |   3 | macchiato    | 1
   1 |   1 | cappuccino   | 500
   1 |   2 | cappuccino   | 500
```

> SELECT * from item;

```
   iname      | itype 
--------------+----------- 
 cappuccino   | hot drink 
 macchiato    | hot drink 
 orange juice | hot drink
```

Comment: so you want a list of clients that bought every possible item at least once? And why without Count functions?

Comment: plz provide table structure, data, your query, expected results

Comment: if you want to show all clients that bought all items, there is no need for a count. Count is only to get a number of fetched rows. Show us your query. Take a look at Visual join explained https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: You should've showed your existing query. If a client buys several items, something is wrong in your table structure.

Comment: No, its not. Dont use comment box to paste in important question related information. Edit your question and add the asked information.

Comment: if you know that you have 3 items total in item table.. you can query like: 
select cid from buys group by cid having count(distinct iname) = 3;

Answer (score 0):

if you know that you have 3 items in item table then you can do:

```
select cid from buys group by cid 
having count(distinct iname) = 3;
```

or if you prefer to nested

```
select cid from buys group by cid 
having count(distinct iname) = (select count(iname) from item);
```

and if you really want something without `count`, not a nice query but  works:

```
select cid from buys group by cid
having group_concat(distinct iname order by iname) like 'cappuccino,macchiato,orange juice'
```

*remember to have items order by name in the like match, see query above*